# Replacing the NavWalker dropdown element

Tags: php, menus, dropdown

I'm creating a website for my school with **Material Design for Bootstrap** and the **NavWalker** is giving me some issues, I want to change the element of dropdown i.e. from `ul` to `div`. I've tried to edit the **NavWalker**.

```
$output .= "\n$indent<div class=\" dropdown-menu dropdown-primary\" aria-labelledby=\"navbarDropdownMenuLink\" >\n";
```

I've edited the code and replaced the DIV instead of UL but don't know how to close the DIV. When I opened the Source Code it display like this

```
<div class=" dropdown-menu dropdown-promary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLin*k" >
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-60"><a title="About Us" href="http://example.com/about/">About Us</a></li>
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-63"><a title="Year Plan" href="http://example.com/year-plan/">Year Plan</a></li>
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-64"><a title="Staff" href="http://example.com/staff/">Staff</a></li>
    <li  class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-65"><a title="Fee and Uniform" href="http://example.com/fee-and-uniform">Fee and Uniform</a></li>
</ul>
```

This spoiled my  navbar! Please help if anyone knows how to solve this issue. These are the links to NavWalker and the one that I've edited.

The original NavWalker file in text file **[Original NavWalker](https://appfunky.000webhostapp.com/wp-custom/141222311211518_ORIGINAL.txt)**

The original NavWalker file in text file **[The Modified One](https://appfunky.000webhostapp.com/wp-custom/141222311211518-MODIFIED.txt)**

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `end_lvl` method of `Walker_Nav_Menu` as well. This is what you would need to add:

```
public function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
        $t = '';
        $n = '';
    } else {
        $t = "\t";
        $n = "\n";
    }
    $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );
    $output .= "$indent</div>{$n}";
}
```

The only change from the original is the `</ul>` was changed to `</div>`

Comment: Jacob, do you have any recommended sources online on how we can expose anchor links instead of li elements, since this user wanted to use a div element instead of a unordered list parent? I feel stuck on how to change elements for sub menus with the nav walker.